# Copy-Paste range values to another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code below which works in some way. The point is that when a value is inserted in column F5 i.e. 10, the value is copied and pasted in column W5, so W5 is 10.

My problem is that if I change the value in W5 from 10 to 8, the code does not return anymore 10 even though I set in my code that W5 must take only the value from F5.

The main point is that I want to prevent the users to change the values in column W5:W100, as those values must be only the values taken from column F5:F100.

> ```
> Dim cellbc As Range
>          Application.EnableEvents = False
>             For Each cellbc In Target
>              If Application.Intersect(cellbc, Range("f5:f100")).Copy Then
>                 Application.Intersect(cellbc, Range("W5:W100")).Paste
>              End If
>        Next cellbc
>          Application.EnableEvents = True
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.

If you need F5 to be the same as W5, you could just use the formula F5 = W5 in Excel - no need for VBA.

If you need it protected, you can use worksheet protection.

If you need to copy and paste the entire column over-

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("F5:F100").Value2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("W5:W100").Value2
```

Comment: yes, this was what I was doing before. I was just using in Excel F5 = W5. The problem was that people were pasting different values in column W5, henceforth it was not picking up anymore the value from F5. That is why I tried to create a VBA code. Even though they will paste a value in cell W5, the code will rejected and it would still pick up the value from F5

Comment: If you need people to not change things, I'd recommend protecting the worksheet. You can also make it so that you only protect some of the worksheet from changes, while letting people edit the rest of the sheet if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is checking to see whether the changed cell was in the range F5:F100 .

When you change cell W5, the Application.Intersect function returns false, and the copy/paste operation doesn't complete.

If you need to make sure that any change in the cells W5:W100 is overwritten immediately by the value in F5:F100, you need to check whether either the source or destination range was changed; and then I would suggest just copying the entire range (F5:F100) over.

Alternatively you could protect the range W5:W100 so it cannot be edited from the spreadsheet. To do this, you first select all the cells the user CAN edit, then go to Format-->Cells-->Protection and UNCHECK the "locked" checkbox. Next, select the cells in W5:W100 , repeat the above and make sure they are "locked". Finally, protect the entire spreadsheet (Tools--> protection-->protect sheet) and uncheck the "allow users to select locked cells" box. Add a password (or don't... the locking mechanism works either way, but it will be harder for the user to override it if you have a password) and you're good to go.

Of course if you go the above route, you don't really need the VBA any more and you could just have an "=F5" in cell W5, etc.